# JPA Container managed transactions - how to update multiple entities in the same transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I'm still new to JPA and how the entity manager works.  I have an application configured with container managed transactions, and I'm trying to figure out how to persist multiple objects in a single transaction.  Here is what I tried first:

```
@Stateless
public class UserManager{
 @PersistenceContext(unitname="dataPortal")
 EntityManager em;

 public void insertUser(User user)
 {
  em.getTransaction().begin();
  ChangeEvent event = new ChangeEvent("user created");
  em.persist(u);
  em.persist(event);
  em.getTransaction().commit();
 }

}
```

This throws an illegal state exception when I try to get the transaction. I found out through reading that you aren't suppose to touch the transaction when it is container managed.

What I want to do is **make sure that the User and ChangeEvent objects are persisted in the same transaction.**  How can I enforce that with container managed transactions?

Comment: I notice you want to add events when updating or creating entities. Have a look at CDI Events or @Stereotypes. It will help you avoid putting all the boiler plate codes in your beans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you already said, the transactions are managed by the container.

If you want that both `User` and `ChangeEvent` are persisted in the same transaction just annotate your method the following way:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER) 
public void insertUser(User user)
     {
      ChangeEvent event = new ChangeEvent("user created");
      em.persist(u);
      em.persist(event);
     }
```

This should do the trick. If you have further questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like this is just what I needed. Your answer helped me find a great article on managing transactions. (http://www.javabeat.net/managing-transactions-in-ejb-3-0)